# Mapping to an element of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, nhibernate, mapping

I have a *class* **Parent** which contains an array of 3 **Child** *class* objects (**Child[] ChildArray**).
I have a *Database Table* **MyTable** with fields **[FLD_01]**, **[FLD_02]**, **[FLD_03]**.

How do I map **[FLD_01]** to **ChildArray[0]**, **[FLD_02]** to **ChildArray[1]** etc?

Comment: @npeBeg: Just wondering: are you aware of one-to-many relations in a RDMBS?

Comment: unfortunately I can not change the structure of DB, so the only thing I can do is to proceed this "proctologist's way" despite I cry everytime I look into the DB :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it like this:

```
class Parent
{

  public Parent()
  {
    Children = new Child[3];
  }

  public Child[] Children { get; private set; }

  private Child1 { get { return Child[0]; } set { Child[0] = value; } }
  private Child2 { get { return Child[1]; } set { Child[1] = value; } }
  private Child3 { get { return Child[2]; } set { Child[2] = value; } }
}
```

The easily map it as separate properties.

```
<property name="Child1" />
<property name="Child2" />
<property name="Child3" />
```

---

Probably best solution is to just map it to another table.

```
<array table="Children">
  <key name="Parent_FK"/>
  <index name="array_index"/>
  <composite-element>
    <property name="Foo"/>
    <property name="Bar"/>
  </composite-element>
</array>
```

Comment: it would be nice if I had only 3 Child items.. but there are 10 and every Child item contain 5 fields..
is there any other solution?

Comment: You always need to specify all the columns you have in the database in your mapping file. If there is 10 times the same 5 fields, you need to map 50 columns, there is no way around. If you want to avoid it, avoid this 50 columns and map the whole stuff into another table.